# AWS CodeDeploy: How to check if the current instance is the last in the deployment and create Cloudfront invalidation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-cloudfront, aws-code-deploy

Hello I am unfamiliar with shell scripting but I was wondering if it is possible for the current instance to check if it is the last instance in the deployment and create a Cloudfront invalidation in one of the hooks?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to find out if the current instance is the last in the deployment. Such a method is flaky and error prone anyway. There are several different deployment configurations which govern how CodeDeploy service deploys code (AllAtOnce/HalfAtATime) [1] so it is not possible to have 1 instance as last instance as sometimes multiple instances batch maybe the *last instance*.

So a better engineering approach would be to put your CodeDeploy deployment as a stage in CodePipeline. As a subsequent stage (after deployment), add a Build stage (CodeBuild) and run the invalidation command from the buildspec in CodeBuild. This will make sure that your Build stage (i.e. invalidation command) will only be run after a successful deployment to all instances.

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployment-configurations.html